# need help with dpkg. (last edit)

Tags: clamav

-$ sudo apt install clamdscan

--E: dpkg interrupted, you must manaually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

$-sudo dpkg --configure -a

dpkg: error: parsing file 'var/lib/dpkg/updates/0001 near line 0: --newline in field name '#padding'

i shut it off while it was updating.

im just gonna backup and run the scan with remove and see what happens.. nvm

Comment: You need to stop editing and changing your question. You need to remove the offensive language. I give up.

Comment: yeah well i cant open clamtk or clamav; update, remove or install...

Answer (score 1):

Open the `ClamTk` application. Install it if you don't already have it.

Click on the `History` icon.

[image]

Click on the report that you'd like to review, then click `View`.

[image]

**Update #1:**

After reviewing the history report, decide if the reported infected file is really a "false positive", or if has a real chance to be infected.

If you believe it's a "false positive", wait until the next scheduled scan and see if the file appears again. If it doesn't, it was a "false positive".

If you believe that there's a real chance that the file is infected, delete it.

**Update #2:**

**The user completely changed the question again!! I give up.**

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately the OP edited it - again - in a way that radically changes the question itself. Now your answer is completely disconnected. I think they don't know what to ask because they don't know what they're doing. I'm suspecting they're running ClamAV in WSL. If true that's just ridiculous, me thinks.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I noticed the OP edit change just now, and updated my answer :-)

Comment: ok.  it says dpkf interrupted, you must manaually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Comment: @serverfarm1  You need to stop editing and changing your question. You need to remove the offensive language. I give up.

Comment: im just using bash btw...

Comment: sudo clamscan -ri / | --move-/C:users/******/Desktop?

Comment: then i also need to know which website i can upload the files too for further verification like i know nheqminer is and so is claymore but the other ones.

Comment: well homies i ran it with --remove and it removed 4 infected files and my bootup was not affected at all but, it cant remove 12 of the files. with my limited library information books i am almost positive its just cuz they are in use.

Comment: I need help opening 18.04 Windows developer bash and since the networking is disabled when im in SM w/networking i know I need to dual boot. Im scared to take the plunge. Clamscan -ri --remove --bell / will terminate the 12 infected files in use while im using regular 10 pro admin mode.